# how can i had a hue shifting filter over a gif?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a .gif file on my site that i'd like to edit so i can have a constant hue shifting filter over it but if someone were to click and drag it itd appear as normal, can someone help please?

I don't want just a rainbow to be layered on my gif, but I need it to be constantly shifting hue like a rainbow if that makes sense.

I've tried to figure it out but I cant. also sorry for any bad english

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is not as hard as you may think. It only requires a CSS 'animation' with `@keyframes` that changes the colors in you image through `filter: hue-rotate(...)`, unless the image gets hovered or activated with the mouse/tapped.

**snippet**

```css
/*
  keep rotating the filter unless the image
  is hovered or activated...
*/

.filtered:not(:where(:hover, :active)) {
  animation: animated-filter 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes animated-filter {
  0% {
    filter: hue-rotate( 0deg)
  }
  50% {
    filter: hue-rotate(360deg)
  }
  100% {
    filter: hue-rotate( 0deg)
  }
}


/* Just eye-candy for the demo */
.wrapper {
  width: 16rem;
  height: 16rem;
}

.wrapper img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="filtered" src="https://picsum.photos/320?random=1">
</div>
```